# отправка zip файлов на сервер

Tags: c#

Имеется 150 квитанций в одном pdf файле. Этот pdf файл делится на 150 отдельных pdf-файлов. Каждые 50 файлов формируются в архив, который затем передается на сервер. При использовании данных методов почему-то формируется всего один архив, содержащий первые 50 квитанций. При проверке точкой останова все квитанции отправляются в архивы, то есть получается, что формируется 3 архива по 50 квитанций. При обычном запуске такого нет. В чем может быть причина ?

```
 protected override void RunExchange()
        {
            Log.Debug("Старт");
            
            try
            {

                if (ImportBills)
                {
                    ExchangeBills();
                    CompleteBillsInfoReading();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex.Message);
            }
        }


 private void ExchangeBills()
        
{
           
            string path = _taskInfo.PDFPath;
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
               ExchangeBillsPDFAsync(path);
                
            }

            else { Log.Info("Файла не существует"); }
}
```

```
private async Task ExchangeBillsPDFAsync(string path)
        {
            
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
            File.Copy(path, Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename), true);

            string resultPdfText = "";

            ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();

            PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(filename, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfr = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(filename);

            Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
            Document.Compress = true;
            doc.Open();
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfr.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                resultPdfText += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfr, i);
            }

            int j = 0;
            int chet = 0;
            int arhShet = 1;
            string[] sourceText = resultPdfText.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            for (int i = 0; i < sourceText.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (sourceText[i].Contains("ИЗВЕЩЕНИЕ"))
                {
                    i += 4;
                    string dateStr = sourceText[i].Substring(sourceText[i].IndexOf("ПЕРИОД") + 7);

                    DateTime date = default;
                    date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);

                    i++;
                    string ls = sourceText[i].Trim();
                    // ls = ls.Substring(sourceText[i].Length - 10);

                    PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();

                    outputDocument.Version = inputDocument.Version;

                    outputDocument.Info.Title = String.Format("Page {0} of {1}", j + 1, inputDocument.Info.Title);
                    outputDocument.Info.Creator = inputDocument.Info.Creator;

                    outputDocument.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[j]);
                    string pdfName = String.Format("Bills_keyField_{0}{1}.pdf", ls, date.ToString("Myyyy"));
                    outputDocument.Save(pdfName);
                    zip.AddFile(pdfName);


                    chet++;
                    j++;
                    if (chet == 50 || inputDocument.Pages.Count == j)
                    {
                        string zipName = $@"arhive_{arhShet}.zip";
                        zip.Save(zipName);


                        string APIKey = _taskInfo.ApiKey;
                        string dataType = "ZIP";
                        string dbFileName = _taskInfo.Name;

                        bool success = await SendData(dbFileName, APIKey, dataType, zipName);
                       
                        zip = new ZipFile();
                        chet = 0;
                        arhShet++;

                        
                    }

                }
            
            }
            
        }

        public static async Task<bool> SendData(string baseName, string apiKey, string dataType, string zipToUpload)
        {
           
           
            string fileName = $"{zipToUpload}";
            RestClient client = new RestClient("https://jul.ashx");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment;filename={fileName}");
            request.AddHeader("ImportOptions", $"basename={baseName};apikey={apiKey}");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic AaaaA");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
            byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(zipToUpload);
            request.AddParameter("application/zip", fileContent, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

            return response.IsSuccessful;


        }
```

Comment: Покажите код метода, где вы вызываете `ExchangeBillsPDFAsync`. Проблема скорее всего в нем.

Comment: private void ExchangeBills()



        {
      

            string path = _taskInfo.PDFPath;
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                ExchangeBillsPDFAsync(path);
                
            }



            else { Log.Info("Файла не существует"); }
        }

Comment: Вставьте код прямо в пост, пост можно редактировать. Этот метод содержит ошибку, но еще теперь надо знать, откуда он вызывается, где верхняя точка вызова в этой последовательности. Метод Main или обработчик события? Покажите.

Comment: нет, не метод Main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете просто так вызвать асинхронный метод из синхронного. Ваш вызов не дождется его завершения. Исправить это можно так, использовать `await`.

```
private async Task ExchangeBillsAsync()  
{
    string path = _taskInfo.PDFPath;
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        await ExchangeBillsPDFAsync(path);
    }
    else { Log.Info("Файла не существует"); }
}
```

И далее наверх по стеку вызовов надо сделать то же самое.

Пока не доберетесь до самой верхней точки. Вот там надо уже смотреть, что это за метод, и как с ним быть.

---

С переопределенным методом не все так просто, потому что как вы сказали, оно не дожидается завершения выполнения, если не ждать окончания асинхронной операции. Поэтому если решать в лоб, то надо либо "запустил и забыл", либо блокировать вызывающий поток. Это чревато дедлоками, но в вашем случае может прокатить.

Костыль, вариант номер 1.

```
protected override async void RunExchange() // async void - плохо
{
    Log.Debug("Старт");
            
    try
    {
        if (ImportBills)
        {
            await ExchangeBillsAsync();
            CompleteBillsInfoReading();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Костыль, вариант номер 2.

```
protected override void RunExchange()
{
    Log.Debug("Старт");
            
    try
    {
        if (ImportBills)
        {
            ExchangeBillsAsync().Wait(); // блокировать поток - плохо
            CompleteBillsInfoReading();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Правильный вариант - это `async Task` и изменение базового класса, если возможно. И вызов этого метода через `await` снаружи.

Правильное решение через изменение базового класса

```
protected override async Task RunExchangeAsync()
{
    Log.Debug("Старт");
            
    try
    {
        if (ImportBills)
        {
            await ExchangeBillsAsync();
            CompleteBillsInfoReading();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

И вызов через `await`.

```
await RunExchangeAsync();
```

Comment: дополнила вопрос, спасибо

Comment: @jul `protected override void RunExchange()` это похоже на часть чего-то, у вас синхронный базовый класс, это не есть хорошо. Что за тип приложения? Костыль конечно легко воткнуть, но лучше этого не делать.

Comment: библиотека классов

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, поняла

Comment: @jul дописал в ответ правильное решение, к которому по возможности стоило бы стремиться.